# IONIC - Why ionic application did not run correctly on device?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have tested my application using `ionic-serve` and everything run normally. 
But, when i tried it using device, the application will first run the splash screen (which is not run when using ionic serve) and nothing happen, only white screen.

Can somebody please help me with this situation?
I have no idea about what happen.

Comment: Due to errors related to app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

The white screen issue often occurs on devices and not in the browser when you are injecting something into a module that kicks off your app. Try to figure out which one, and remove it (if it's not being used) or update it.

Comment: I dont get it sir. I'm so sorry, can you explain it again to me with a simple explanation, i'm really newbie at this. @GarrettMacMac

Comment: @lloistborn Sure take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558333/4642530). You see these features that are being adding into the project— `ngStorage`, `ngAnimate`—these are called modules and here they are being injected into your starter module (likely called starter too if you used an ionic starter and didn't change it). If there's an issue with one, its out of date or your not calling one in the project it can cause a white screen when tested on mobile. Try removing the ones you are not using. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to check for errors in the log. To see them, type the address `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome, and click on your app. You'll need to make sure your device has usb debugging turned on.

Comment: Please post a screenshot.